# Jupyter Lab on WSl2, ubuntu 20.04, windows 11 will not open and error saying missing NodeJS

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I have 2 problems (not open browser and missing nodejs) but the main issue I want to focus and fix is the nodejs is missing.

I'm at my wits end and even chat GPT advice was not really helpful in this case.
I know nodejs is not necessary for tensorflow, but I plan to use it later.
Jupyter Lab on WSL2 will not open my browser, no problem as I can copy the link and paste it on brave browser, but the issue comes after I paste the link as I get this error.
`[W 2023-02-22 17:56:46.354 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs`

I do not have this problem when I do it on native windows, only on WSL2.

I explained my workflow below. If you can tell me where I went wrong or a better solution then would appreciate

**my workflow if you want to reproduce it**
Here is the instructions from their website https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2
(both work but when I add jupyter lab to the method, things break down)

- tensorflow 2.11 does not work on windows and can only run on linux so they recommended WSL2
- Turn on WSL2 for windows 11
- in powershell paste `wsl --install -d Ubuntu-20.04`
- create my linux account and then paste `curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` to download mini conda
- to install miniconda, paste `bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`
- restart WSL2 to have conda working. Then activate conda
- to create new env, paste `conda create --name tf-wsl2 python=3.9`
- to activate env, paste `conda activate tf-wsl2`
- to get the CUDA API and cuDNN library, paste `conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`
- for the paths, paste `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/`, `mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d`
- then paste `mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d`
- then paste `echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/' > $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`
- paste `pip install --upgrade pip`
- install tensorflow paste `pip install tensorflow`
- to check if GPU work then paste `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('Num GPUs Available: ', len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"`
- to install `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`
- to run Jupyter lab paste `jupyter lab`

the port will be open and server created, but my chrome or brave browser (default) will not open. I copy the link and paste into my brave or chrome browser and opens, but then I get the error
`[W 2023-02-22 17:56:46.354 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs`

**other things I have done**
I think that nodejs is not updated so I
`sudo apt update sudo apt install nodejs`

another method is
`conda install -c conda-forge nodejs"`

another is reinstall jupyter labs, reinstall nodejs, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with you. In my case, I have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly, but still got an error like dynamic libraries xxx.so not found.
I think this is a bug in wsl2 which can not load .so from `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`